# Magento 2 - Admin panel product image uploading gives error

Tags: magento2

I am receiving below error while uploading any image for product.

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   /var/www/sitename.com/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
>   on line 344

Is there anyone who receives same error?

Comment: Is  GD library  is installed in your environment

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check php extension that are need it for M2.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

in your case, maybe the problem is missing: gd, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both

Comment: I have confirmed that GD library is installed over server. Is there any other possibility for not working?